# unable to extract text using tika in sagemaker, what is the reason for this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, text-extraction, apache-tika, amazon-textract

code I've used:

```
from tika import parser
headers = {
'X-Tika-PDFextractInlineImages': 'true',
}
text = parser.from_file("pdffiles/BG1309020268.pdf",headers=headers)
print(text)
text = parser.from_buffer("pdffiles/BG1307018880.pdf")
text_content=text.get('content')
print(text_content)
```

working perfectly locally, but when I execute this in sagemaker studio getting result as None.

Comment: Missing dependencies? Did you try the steps in the troubleshooting guide? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika